# Efficient way to sub Queries in Linq

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

here is my linq code:

```
BOOK entity = db.BOOKS
             .Where(s => s.ID == (from p in db.LIBRARY
                                  from b in db.BOOKS
                                  where (p.ID == 123) && (p.idpage == b.idpage)
                                  select b.fields));
```

My actual oracle code is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BOOKS.ID 
FROM LIBRARY,BOOKS 
WHERE LIBRARY.ID = 123 AND LIBRARY.ID = BOOKS.ID
```

But its showing the error in s.ID that..

```
Delegate 'System.Func Project.Models.BOOKS,int,bool' does not take 1 arguments
```

Why does this happen? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Sry guys. I didn't mention abt delete operation. Now I edited & clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL is using a join, so you can do the same thing in LINQ. Either of these approaches will suffice:

```
// join
var query = (from b in db.BOOKS
            join p in db.LIBRARY on b.IdPage equals p.IdPage 
            where p.ID == 123
            select b.Id).Distinct();

// 2 from statements (SelectMany) can also be used as a join
var query = (from b in db.BOOKS
            from p in db.LIBRARY
            where p.ID == 123 && b.IdPage == p.IdPage 
            select b.Id).Distinct();

// fluent syntax
var query = db.BOOKS
              .Where(b => db.LIBRARY.Any(p =>
                  p.ID == 123 && b.IdPage == p.IdPage))
              .Select(b => b.Id)
              .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

s.ID is comparing to an Enumerable, so you get the error.
At the end of the LINQ query, add a SingleOrDefault().

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery returns a sequence of values, not a single values, so you can't compare it to a scalar property like `ID`. You should use `First` on the result of the subquery to get the first result (or `Single` if there should be only one)

```
BOOK entity = db.BOOKS
             .Where(s => s.ID == (from p in db.LIBRARY
                                  from b in db.BOOKS
                                  where (p.ID == 123) && (p.idpage == b.idpage)
                                  select b.fields).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the navigation properties on your BOOKS class to do something like this:

```
var bookIds = db.BOOKS.Where(b => b.LIBRARIES.Any(l => l.ID == 123))
     .Select(b => b.ID)
```